# How to add custom view on Navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add custom view on navigation bar. I am not sure how to implement it. Any help appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement custom view on navigation bar easily.
Check the below it will be helped.

[image: Custom View Navigation Top Bar]

Hoping it will be helped.

Answer (score -1):

This is a example of how to add a Image instead of a Title String

```
func setupTitle(){

    let logo = UIImage(named: "ImageFileName")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```